# PMD Rule for making comparisons against constants

Tags: java, coding-style, checkstyle, pmd

I have a formal coding policy that when doing comparisons against constants, that the constant [non-primitive] should be compared to the object in question.

For example:

```
final String BEST_NAME = "Jim";
String myName = "Bob";
```

The comparison should be

```
BEST_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(myName)
```

I can not seem to find the PMD specific rule for this... does it exist?

Comment: You're stating two separate rules here: one, that the constant should come first; second, that 'the comparison should be ... `equalsIgnoreCase().` I doubt that the second is what you intended. Please clarify.

Comment: Nope, the case comparison has nothing to do with it, its just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can not seem to find the PMD specific rule for this... does it exist?

It is highly unlikely that it does<sup>1</sup>, because such a rule is project (or maybe organization) specific.  Indeed, for *most* people / projects / organizations, such a rule would be "just plain wrong".  Use of case insensitive comparisons for *all* String constants is not normal / standard / best practice.

However, I did find this rule that is *similar* to what you are asking for:

- [PositionLiteralsFirstInCaseInsensitiveComparisons](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.2/rules/java/design.html#PositionLiteralsFirstInCaseInsensitiveComparisons) - which says, if you are comparing strings using `equalsIgnoreCase` THEN you should use the literal value as the target.

---

If you need to, you can write custom PMD rules for your project / organization ... if this is what you need.

Reference:

- [How to write a PMD rule](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/howtowritearule.html).

---

<sup>1 - OK, it is possible someone else also has this requirement, and has already written such a PMD rule.  However, it is probably more effort to track down the code and repurpose it, than it is to write the PMD rule from scratch ...</sup>

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  This question tells the OP the (probably) most effective way to satisfy his requirement.  And it answers his literal question too.

Comment: I'm not convinced his actual question has anything to do with case-insensitivity. Neither the title nor the first sentence says so. I've asked him to clarify.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question was about comparisons, not about the case insensitivity issue [which is a rule]... 

I see the link lead me to the answer that I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something similar to the [PositionLiteralsFirstInCaseInsensitiveComparisons](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.2/rules/java/design.html#PositionLiteralsFirstInCaseInsensitiveComparisons) PMD rule.

The rule states that the constant value should be first in comparisons. 
This works most of the time for inline (e.g. `myName.equals("Jim")`) cases, however **it will never find the example you showed** us (e.g. `myName.equalsIgnoreCase(BEST_NAME)`) because PMD cannot make reference to constant fields.

I would recommend the use of **[FaultHunter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/modules/faulthunter/)** which can detect these kind of rule violations as well, and yet it still uses the familiar *Position Literals First In Comparisons* name for the rule, so it is very easy to adapt. You can see an example for yourself [on this demo page](https://sonarqube.sourcemeter.com/resource/index/Hibernate:hibernate-core:src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fhibernate%2Fbytecode%2Finternal%2Fjavassist%2FFieldTransformer.java?display_title=true&metric=97&rule=462).